# unsupported major.minor version 52.0visual studio 2015 community

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Segue em anexo a imagem do erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O número de versão que é mostrado no erro descreve a versão do JRE com o qual o arquivo de classe é compatível.

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

De acordo com o [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout), a ordem da referência dos valores são:

- Java SE 9 = 53
- Java SE 8 = 52
- Java SE 7 = 51
- Java SE 6.0 = 50
- Java SE 5.0 = 49
- JDK 1.4 = 48
- JDK 1.3 = 47
- JDK 1.2 = 46
- JDK 1.1 = 45

Veja mais detalhes em: [The JavaTM Virtual Machine Specification 2nd edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html)

A versão 52.0 se refere à versão específica do JDK, que neste caso se refere ao JDK 8.

- [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) - up to API 24+
- [JDK 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) - up to API 23
- [JDK 1.6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) - up to API 20

Para corrigir o problema, você deve tentar executar seu código com uma versão mais recente do Java JRE ou especificar o parâmetro de destino do compilador para instruí-lo a criar um código compatível com versões anteriores do Java.